# Why is the integer in the struct a garbage values even though it was changed?

Tags: c, memory, struct

So, I implemented split in C, now I know `strtok` exists, but I wanted to implement it, so my function returns a struct that has the string array and the length, which is decided by the number of times the delimiter occurs and whether it's the first value or not, here's the code.

**split.h**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_delm(char *, char);
char *make_str(char);
struct split_output {
    char **arr;
    int size;
};
typedef struct split_output split_arr;
split_arr *split(char *, char);
```

**split.c**

```
#include "split.h"

int count_delm(char *str, char delm) {
    register int lpvar = 0;
    register int counter = 0;
    while (str[lpvar] != '\0') {
        if (str[lpvar] == delm) {
            counter++;
        }
        lpvar++;
    }
    return counter;
}

char *make_str(char ch) {
    char *ret_str = (char *)malloc(2);
    ret_str[0] = ch;
    ret_str[1] = '\0';
    return ret_str;
}

split_arr *split(char *str, char delm) {
    int num_delm = count_delm(str, delm);
    char **final_arr;
    register int lpvar = 0;
    register int arr_counter = 0;
    char *concat_str = (char *)malloc(2);
    int ret_size = 0;
    if (str[0] == delm) {
        concat_str = make_str(str[1]);
        final_arr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (num_delm));
        ret_size = num_delm;
        lpvar++;
    } else {
        concat_str = make_str(str[0]);
        final_arr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (num_delm + 1));
        ret_size = num_delm + 1;
    }
    while (1) {
        if (str[lpvar + 1] != '\0') {
            if (str[lpvar + 1] != delm) {
                concat_str = strcat(concat_str, make_str(str[lpvar + 1]));
                lpvar++;
            } else {
                final_arr[arr_counter] = concat_str;
                arr_counter++;
                if (str[lpvar + 2] != '\0') {
                    lpvar++;
                    lpvar++;
                    concat_str = make_str(str[lpvar]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            arr_counter++;
            final_arr[arr_counter] = concat_str;
            printf("%s is the last at pos %d\n", concat_str, arr_counter);
            break;
        }
    }
    split_arr *ret_struct = (split_arr *)malloc(sizeof(split_arr));
    (*ret_struct).size = ret_size;
    (*ret_struct).arr = final_arr;
    return ret_struct;
}
```

That was the code of the split implementation, here's the code that tests it.
**test.c**

```
#include "split.h"

int main() {
    char *x = "lryabruahsdfads";
    split_arr output = *(split(x, 'a'));
    char **read = output.arr;
    int len = output.size;
    int loop = 0;
    printf("size: %d", len - 1);
    for (loop = 0; loop < len; loop++) {
        puts(*(read + loop));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output when executed:

```
ds is the last at pos 4
size: 3lry
bru
hsdf
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why is output.size `3lry`? I de-referenced the struct pointer to get the struct so there's nothing wrong with that. I can't find the error, I've been trying to debug for almost an hour.

Comment: I'm sure there are other issues, but *one* major problem is the way you use `strcat()`.  It is your responsibility when you call that function to ensure that the destination array is large enough to accommodate the extra characters after the string already contained within, but the code presented flagrantly fails to do that.

Comment: You aren't printing a newline after your size.  The 'garbage' is from your looped `puts`.

Comment: Put a `\n` after `%d`.  The problem is after where you think it is.

Comment: Not to pound salt in the wound, but that function is also a memory leak factory. The only two code paths after `char *concat_str=(char*)malloc(2);`, the if-else,  *both* overwrite `concat_str` with some other address/value.

Comment: `concat_str=strcat(concat_str,make_str(str[lpvar+1]);` You are leaking memory from `make_str` and there is no space in `concat_str`. You have to `realloc` first, and then just `strcat` it.

Comment: @KamilCuk ;))))))))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `split.c` file over here:

```
else{
   arr_counter++; //comment this line
   final_arr[arr_counter]=concat_str;
   printf("%s is the last at pos %d\n",concat_str,arr_counter);
   break;
  }
```

You are incrementing variable `arr_counter` which you should not because you already incremented it inside the if. Just comment out this line and your code works fine.
And your output is fine just add a line return to the printf statements like:

```
printf("size: %d \n",len-1);
```